# Emptying the trash failed with "can't copy" on Yosemite

Tags: macos, usb, trash

While using empty stack securely under Yosemite, it halted with the message:

> You can't copy the item `InfoPlist.strings` because its name is too long or includes characters that are invalid on the destination volume.

What's the matter and, more important, what can I do about it?

PS. It might be that the `InfoPlist.strings` is located on an MS-DOS (FAT32) partition on an USB disk. (On which I lost 130 GB because I deleted that data.)

Comment: I'm puzzled - you're stuck emptying trash because you're erasing data you accidentally threw in the trash… rather than just getting it back from the trash?

Comment: Yes, that true. I just wanted to delete the data  permanently. However it moved to the trash. And now it occupies 130 GB on a 200 GB partition.

Comment: In the mean time I lost also the content of another netwerk disc. I can't proof that it is because of emptying the trash but I did not acces that drive since my attempt to empty the trash. (it may be related to the question 'OS X Empty Trash is deleting all files on computer'?)

I am still glad I changed from Windows to OSX but this  is ridicules. Emptying a trash is so very basic that one could rely on it unconditionally. 

And yes, I am aware that Apple sells hardware and may discouraging the freeing any disc space, but if you search on 'trash empty' you wil find to much serious problems.

Comment: "You can't copy the item InfoPlist.strings because its name is too long or includes characters that are invalid on the destination volume" sounds more like you're trying to copy data *to* the FAT disk.

Comment: Yes, but I was really using 'Secure Empty Trash'

Answer (score 1):

Open the trash folder, try to rename few sub files and main directory in which the file content and then try to empty the trash. By doing the same, it will not show error and will empty the trash.

For me this worked. Hope it also helps you.